# Jest - How to mock aws-sdk sqs.receiveMessage methode

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, aws-sdk

I try mocking sqs.receiveMessage function which imported from aws-sdk.

**Here is my code(sqsHelper.js):**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

export default class SqsHelper {


  static SqsGetMessagesTest = () => {

    const sqs = new AWS.SQS({
      apiVersion: serviceConfig.sqs.api_version,
      region: serviceConfig.sqs.region,
    });

    const queueURL =
      "https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<1234>/<4567>";

    const params = {
      AttributeNames: ["SentTimestamp"],
      MaxNumberOfMessages: 10,
      MessageAttributeNames: ["All"],
      QueueUrl: queueURL,
      VisibilityTimeout: 20,
      WaitTimeSeconds: 20,
    };


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sqs.receiveMessage(params, async (recErr, recData) => {
        if (recErr) {
          reject(recErr);
        } else if (recData.Messages) {
          console.info(`Message count: ${recData.Messages.length}`);
          resolve(recData.Messages);
        }
      });
    });
  };
}
```

**And here is the test file(sqsHelper.test.js):**

```
import SqsHelper from "../../helpers/sqsHelper.js";
import { SQS } from "aws-sdk";

const dumyData = { Messages: [{ name: "123", lastName: "456" }] };
const sqs = new SQS();


describe("Test SQS helper", () => {

  test("Recieve message", async () => {

    jest.spyOn(sqs, 'receiveMessage').mockReturnValue(dumyData);

    // check 1
    const res1 = await sqs.receiveMessage();
    console.log(`res: ${JSON.stringify(res1, null, 2)}`)
    expect(res1).toEqual(dumyData);

    // check 2
    const res2 = await SqsHelper.SqsGetMessagesTest();
    console.log(`res2: ${JSON.stringify(res2, null, 2)}`);
    expect(res2).toBe(dumyData);

  });
});
```

The problem is that on the first check( which i call the function directly from the test file) i can see that the receiveMessage has been mocked and the results is as expected.

But on the second check(which the function called from the second module "sqsHelper.js") looks that the mock function doe's work and the originalreceiveMessage has been called and it still ask me about credentials.

This is the error:

```
InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is
invalid.
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are spying on the object from your test: `const sqs = new SQS();` not the one that is created inside the `SqsHelper` on line: ` const sqs = new AWS.SQS({`. This is totally different object. That one is not mocked and the original implementation is called.

Comment: @MarekRozmus  - so how can i mock the original module on the sqsHelper ?       I tried to mock the entire module like this  `const sqs = new SQS();
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  const SQSMocked = {
    receiveMessage: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(dumyData)
  };
  return {
    SQS: jest.fn(() => SQSMocked)
  };
})` But got a timeout issue. This means that the original method was called again.....

Answer (score 1):

The `receiveMessage` should trigger a callback that comes in the params. `receiveMessage` does not return a `Promise`
Try something like this:

```js
const dummyData = { Messages: [{ name: "123", lastName: "456" }] };

const mockReceiveMessage = jest.fn().mockImplementation((params, callback) => callback("", dummyData));

jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual("aws-sdk");

  return {
    ...originalModule,
    SQS: function() { // needs to be function as it will be used as constructor
      return {
        receiveMessage: mockReceiveMessage
      }
    }
  };
})

describe("Test SQS helper", () => {
  test("Recieve message", async () => {
    const res = await SqsHelper.SqsGetMessagesTest();
    expect(res).toBe(dummyData.Messages);
  });

  test("Error response", async () => {
    mockReceiveMessage.mockImplementation((params, callback) => callback("some error"));
    await expect(SqsHelper.SqsGetMessagesTest()).rejects.toEqual("some error");
  });
});
```